# Ruby on Rails - Geocoder view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

Im trying to use [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) for displaying a location based on an address.

My question is, what do I put in the view to show an interactive map once I got the Lat and Long from the address the user inserted in the database?

my address model

```
 belongs_to <another model>
 attr_accessible <all addresses attributes including latitude and longitude>

 geocoded_by :address

 after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

The fields Latitude and Longitude are automatically calculated after I insert the address.

I've followed Ryan's Rail Cast tutorial but at the end, instead of displaying a static image I want to display a map, google maps interactive style. How can I achieve this?

If've taken a look at [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) but couldn't understand how very well like how to get a single map on location in the show view.

Comment: If you have the lat/long, you don't necessarily need the GMFR gem. You could just use the standard Google maps api: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: I have the lat and long beacause Geocoder calculates this when I enter  and submit an address.
Therefore, don't I need to like, "call" the map api in the view with the coords providade by geocoder?

Comment: I understand. But you can use the standard Google Maps JavaScript API snippet for that, no special gem required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails). That gem makes it trivial, and the instructions on how to get the interactive map in your view are quite clear:

(I'll presume your Address model belongs_to a User model. Change names as appropriate.)

If you just want the one specific user on the map, of course you could change the controller:

```
@json = User.find(params[:id]).address.to_gmaps4rails
```

In your view:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

Comment: I can't believe this. I actually was doing that very same code, but nothing was displaying...I can't believe all that was missing was `*= require gmaps4rails` in the application.css file.

Thank you

Comment: @Silver Nice. Love those “doh!” moments.

Answer (score 2):

There are many helpful examples for the Google Maps API available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/). In the simplest case, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lat = <%= @model.latitude %>, 
      lon = <%= @model.longitude %>,
      map;
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Just replace `@model.latitude` and `@model.longitude` with the corresponding geocoded fields in your model.

Comment: It seems to be a simple good idea, but when I try it all I get is a grey box where the map was supposed to be. And yes, i've replaced the @model.latitute/longitude for mine. I've also declared #map_canvas in css setting a height and width. Sorry for these questions im new at this :/